# Flutter - ios not running in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios-build

My flutter code is not running in iOS Simulator but its running in android. I tried Pod deintegrate and pod install but noting works.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWGWs.png

**pubspec.yaml file**

```
name: vaidya_connect
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:

  sdk: '>=3.1.2 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.1.1  form_builder_validators: ^9.1.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
  provider: ^6.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.16.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.6
  flutter_gif: ^0.0.4
  flutter_flavorizr: ^2.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  flutter_gen_runner: ^5.3.2

flutter_gen:
    output: lib/utils/

flavorizr:
  flavors:
    dev:
      app:
        name: "Vaidya Connect Dev"

      android:
        applicationId: "com.avprf.vaidyaconnect.dev"

      ios:
        bundleId: "com.avprf.vaidyaconnect.dev"

    stage:
      app:
        name: "Vaidya Connect Stage"

      android:
        applicationId: "com.avprf.vaidyaconnect.stage"
      ios:
        bundleId: "com.avprf.vaidyaconnect.stage"

    prod:
      app:
        name: "Vaidya Connect"
      android:
        applicationId: "com.avprf.vaidyaconnect"
      ios:
        bundleId: "com.avprf.vaidyaconnect"


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true


  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/fonts/
```

```
Xcode build done.                                            6.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-dev-input-files.xcfilelist'

Error (Xcode): Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-dev-output-files.xcfilelist'

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
```

I tried `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

**Clean the Build:** First, try cleaning the build by going to "Product" in the Xcode menu, and then selecting "Clean Build Folder." This will remove any cached build artifacts that might be causing problems.

**Update CocoaPods:** Make sure you have the latest version of CocoaPods installed by running the following command in your iOS project's directory:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

**Flutter Clean:** Run the following command in the root directory of flutter project

```
flutter clean
```

After updating CocoaPods, update your project's pods by running the following commands in your iOS directory

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Then try to run iOS app.

Comment: Tank you for the answer, but the issue still persists, pod install I’m getting
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`)

Comment: Error (Xcode): Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support
Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-dev-input-files.xcfilelist'


Error (Xcode): Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support
Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-dev-output-files.xcfilelist'


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.

Comment: Found the issue it’s happening because of flutter_flavorizr. I ran the code with different project and successfully ran in ios.

Comment: I don't think we need any flutter package to build flavors. You can remove flutter_flavorizr and do flavoring manually. Let me know if you need help with how to make flavors in flutter